# Jobs scheduled using python_crontab not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, cron

I am using following python code to schedule job in ubuntu.

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(user='username')
job  = cron.new(command='/usr/bin/python3 /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/ScheduleInvoicingUtility.py >> /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/Logs.txt')
job.setall('*/2 * * * *')        
cron.write()
print(cron.render())
```

Code run successfully, and it's render function print output as follow:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/ScheduleInvoicingUtility.py >> /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/Logs.txt
```

But do not know where this job is saved in ubuntu, and also job is not running/working after specified time.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: don't you need admin rights to alter the crontable?

Comment: I can edit crontab using sudo crontab -e command, and i used same user above in my python code.

Comment: so you ran your pyhton script using `sudo` ?

Comment: This python script is being triggered by another cron job. code of cron job is: 0 7 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/ScheduleInvoicingUtility.py >> /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/Logs.txt

Comment: I mean: run the python script corresponding to the snippet using `sudo`, no the Invoicing thingy.

Comment: Didn't get your point, please explain.

Comment: sudo is used when we code directly in shell, in my case i am trying to schedule job using python, not directly in shell.

Comment: I am using this package to get this job done. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab

Comment: cron is stored in /var/spool/cron  under the user name who created the crontab.   i'd check there to make sure your entry is being written.  since you are using sudo it sounds like you are messing with root cron  so you could also run sudo crontab -l  ( if its in sudoers) to check as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fix the issue with minor changes. Here is code which is properly creating the cron job from python:

```
cron = CronTab(user=True)
job  = cron.new(comment='My_Unique_Job', command='/usr/bin/python3 /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/ScheduleInvoicingUtility.py >> /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/Logs.txt')
job.setall('*/2 * * * *')
cron.write()
```

Use this to remove previous jobs with same id.

```
cron.remove_all(comment='My_Unique_Job')
```

Complete code will be:

```
cron = CronTab(user=True)
cron.remove_all(comment='My_Unique_Job')
job  = cron.new(comment='My_Unique_Job', command='/usr/bin/python3 /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/ScheduleInvoicingUtility.py >> /home/(user)/Desktop/Schedular/Logs.txt')
job.setall('*/2 * * * *')
cron.write()
```

Don't forgot to import CronTab:

```
from crontab import CronTab
```

Install python_crontab using pip.

```
pip install python_crontab
```